# No application logging from Grails application?

Tags: grails, log4j, grails-2.1

I have a simple grails app and some logging in the controller.  However, no matter how I configure the logging, I do not see my application log message (even though I can be overwhelmed with grails internal logging).

### Config:

```
// log4j configuration
log4j = {
    // Example of changing the log pattern for the default console appender:
    //
    appenders {
        console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%c{2} %m%n')
        file name:'file', file:'C:\\Users\\C.Ross\\Logs\\Budget.log'
    }
    root {
        warn 'file', 'stdout'
    }

    warn  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
           'org.springframework',
           'org.hibernate',
           'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'

    trace 'grails.app.controller'

}
```

I've also tried

```
trace 'com.ross.budget'
```

and

```
root {
    all 'file', 'stdout'
}
```

But no luck at all.  Even when everything else is logging I do not see the log messages from my app *at all*.  What am I doing wrong?

### Code:

```
 package com.ross.budget

 class BudgetController {

    def index() { 
        redirect(action:"list")
    }

    def list() {
        log.trace "Retrieving all budgets..."
        [budgetList: Budget.all]
    }

    def add() {
        log.trace "Calling add..."
    }

    def show(){
        log.trace "Retrieving budget"
        def budget = Budget.get(params.id)
        [budget: budget]
    }

    def save(){
        log.debug "Creating new budget"
        def budget = new Budget(params)
        budget.save()
        redirect(action:"list")
    }

    def addLineItem(){
        log.trace("Retrieving budget $params.id")
        def budget = Budget.get(params.id)
        log.trace("Creating line item from params")
        def lineItem = new LineItem(params)
        log.debug "Adding line item to budget"
        budget.lineItems.add(lineItem)
        log.trace "Saving budget"
        budget.save()
        log.trace("Redirecting to show ...")
        redirect(action:"show", id:params.id)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is happening because you have the root logger set to warn.

Comment: @Krystian As noted in the question, I've also tried it with the root logger at `all`.  If that doesn't get it ...

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Grails docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#logging) (under **Configuring loggers**), you need `grails.app.controllers`.  Just make the artefact name plural.